# Eclipse - Using a .class file in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, class

As part of a project I was given three files, a partially written .java file where my work will go and two separate .class files.  I created a new Java Project and added the .java file and started adding/editing the starter code.
How/where should I put the .class files?

I tried adding the class files to the bin folder and dragging/dropping them into the package in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You should go to the project's Java Build Path property page and add a Class Folder for those two files. The contents of `bin` will be erased and overwritten without notice.